# What is the difference between charms for Oneiric and Precise?

Tags: juju

I do not understand the difference between an Oneiric charm and a Precise charm. But I know that it is something important.

Can anybody explain this for me?

Answer (score 5):

Oneiric is Ubuntu 11.10, Precise is Ubuntu 12.04. Pick the charm for the version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneric Ocelot) is the previous version of Ubuntu, Behind Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). Ubuntu Precise features updates to Unity, Linux and System changes. For example, Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) includes a feature called HUD which allows you to type for menus in applications instead of having to find the menus on the top bar.